# Masking and histogram of the 3d grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

All

Have reasonable large 3d grid as NumPy array of floats, shape (nx, ny, nz). Have similar (same shape) 3d grid of 1s and 0s, essentially a bitmask. I would like to select data from grid based on bitmask and use them later for a histogram.

What I do now is

```
k = 0
for iz in range(0, nz):
    for iy in range(0, ny):
        for ix in range(0, nx):
            d = data[ix, iy, iz]
            b = bitmap[ix, iy, iz]
            if b > 0:
                droi[k] = d
                k += 1

hist, bins = np.histogram(droi, bins = 200, range=(0.0, dmax))
```

Which is unelegant and slow. I thought about flattening both arrays and multiplying them, and running histogram on whole thing, but 0 is potentially in data as well, so it would change histogram.

Any thoughts how to do it faster and in smaller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `bitmap` to an array of booleans, you can use [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to get the elements of `data` corresponding to the `True` elements in `bitmap`:

```
bitmapbool = numpy.array(bitmap, dtype=bool)
droi = data[bitmapbool]
```